# Plugin wont set Stock level and status - Module wont fire on Product Load

Tags: magento2, event-observer, plugin

Please advise on this 
I'm trying to update a stock level and status via a seperate API, and will code that when I get this working, however, I'm struggling to even set the Stock status and count to update based on information I've found on the net.

I need to run this before the product loads, as the product will most likely update and I need the screen to show the correct information. I want to use a product object as I might actually do some update on custom fields too, but for now, I'm starting simple, so any advice would be good.

UPDATE:

So I've gone done the module route, and it doesn't look like my module is firing, here is the files in the module. What kind of debugging can I use? or can anyone see anything obvious:

> /app/code/Olisco/Tpcconnector/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product">
      <plugin name="calltpc" type="Olisco\Tpcconnector\Plugin\ApiCall" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> /app/code/Olisco/Tpcconnector/Plugin/ApiCall.php

```
<?php
namespace Olisco\Tpcconnector\Plugin;

class ApiCall 
{

    public function beforeinitProduct(Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $subject, $result)
    {

        error_log("TEST");
        var_dump("TEST");
         echo "#########";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://dealer.theperformance.co/"); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        $output = curl_exec($ch); 
        curl_close($ch);      

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should not use events to update data. use plugins instead

Comment: you are not saving the product

Comment: @PhilippSander tried the ->save too and it made no difference.

Comment: @Toby Lockyer does your events.xml is under etc/frontend folder?

Answer (score 1):

If you are modifying the data, then you should use `plugins` and not the observers.

You can try creating the after plugin for the `method initProduct` of `class Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product`

Reference Link for using Plugins : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: Perfect. I would prefer to do it properly. This makes more sense...

Comment: This example looks about right too....https://www.emiprotechnologies.com/technical_notes/magento-technical-notes-60/post/how-to-create-and-use-plugins-in-magento-2-444

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite your method name to `beforeInitProduct` instead of `beforeinitProduct`

```
<?php
namespace Olisco\Tpcconnector\Plugin;

class ApiCall 
{

    public function beforeInitProduct(Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $subject, $result)
    {

        error_log("TEST");
        var_dump("TEST");
         echo "#########";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://dealer.theperformance.co/"); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        $output = curl_exec($ch); 
        curl_close($ch);      

        return $result;
    }
}
```